# Computing the $\sigma$-algebra $\sigma ( \{ \{ a \}:a \in \mathbb{Q} \})$ on $\Bbb R$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I found an interesting question in a book.

**Question:** Compute the $\sigma$-algebra $\sigma ( \{ \{ a \}:a \in \mathbb{Q} \})$ on $\mathbb{R}$.

What is interesting to me is that the problem comes  explicitly to show the difficulties that can arise when somebody is looking for an explicit characterization of a generated $\sigma$-algebra.

Now, to me this does not look that difficult, hence I do have the feeling that I am missing something, and I am depicting the all problem too simplistically.

Namely, my line of reasoning is that we can set $\mathbb{Q} := \{ a_1, a_2, \dots \}$, which means that we an explicit enumeration of $\mathbb{Q}$. Hence, we can proceed by taking arbitrary unions of those $\{a_n\}$, and we end up with $\mathbb{Q}$. By complementation we get $\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$, hence we get $\mathbb{R}$.

*Am I wrong?

If so, where?*

Thank you for your time.
As always, any feedback is much appreciated!

Comment: Every $\sigma$-algebra contains both the empty set and the ambient set, so getting $\mathbb R$ to be in the $\sigma$-algebra isn't particularly enlightening (and thus not likely to be of much help).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\Bbb R$ is the set, it's not the $\sigma$-algebra. You're not asked to find whether or not $\Bbb R$ is in this $\sigma$-algebra. You're asked to give a "reasonable" description of which sets can be found in $\sigma(\{\{q\}\mid q\in\Bbb Q\})$.

You have shown that $\Bbb{Q,R\setminus Q,R}$ are all there. But there must be more sets, and the question is which sets are these?

**HINT:** You can show that by taking countable unions once, and complements once, you have generated all the $\sigma$-algebra. What sort of sets will you find there?

Comment: Thus, by following your hint and my enumeration, we should get sets of the form $\bigcup_{i=1}^n \{ a_i \} \subset \mathbb{Q}$, and (by complementation) $\mathbb{R} \setminus \bigcup_{i=1}^n$, right?

Comment: *countable* unions not just finite unions.

Comment: But, actually, if this is the case, (forgetting for a second that I lost the thread of the problem in my original question), I still don't see what is particularly problematic in it.

Comment: I don't understand your second comment.

Comment: But, by taking countable unions, don't we end up with $\mathbb{Q}$. I mean, $\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty \{ a_i \} = \mathbf{Q}$, right? Thus, we sort of end up with what I wrote in the original question. [sure there is a mistake here. If that's the case, forgive the naivete]

Comment: Is $\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty\{a_{5i^4+3}\}=\Bbb Q$? And what about the union $\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty\{a_0\}$? Nowhere it says that the union has to be of distinct sets. Finally, you don't "end up with $\Bbb R$" since that is not a $\sigma$-algebra. Yes, you end up **generating** $\Bbb R$, but this is just like how starting with $0$ and the successor operation you *end up with $\Bbb N$* rather than ending up with $4$ because $SSSS0=4$.